# jQuery Click event and update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am not sure if I am doing the following right but I want my jQuery graph to be triggered by a button and at the same time not needing to postback the entire page therefore the update panel was included. Apparently, the graph loads but somehow I think it did before the postback occured therefore everytime when I click on my 'previewgraph' button, I can see the graph animates then goes back to a blank chart again. Please kindly advice.

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#<%=btnPreviewGraph.ClientID%>") .click(function () {
                alert("Here");
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    // for each result row..
                    $(".extras_result").each(function () {
                        // get the width of the bar from the span html
                        var length = $(this).find("span").html();
                        // Animate the width of the 'p' with a callback function
                        $(this).find("p").animate({ 'width': length }, 2000, function () {
                            // once the bar animation has finished, fade in the results
                            $(this).find("span").fadeIn(300);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>


  <asp:Button ID="btnPreviewGraph" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Preview"/>

             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlPreviewChart" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
             <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPreviewGraph" EventName="Click" />
             </Triggers>
          <ContentTemplate>
     <div class="row">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="<%$ Resources:loyaltyManagerResources, uilblCamQualAccumulatedSpending %>"
                        CssClass="label">
                    </asp:Label>
                               <br /><br />
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="extras_table">
                <tr>
                    <th class="extras_y-desc" scope="row">
                        Male
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div class="extras_result">
                            <p class="extras_p">
                               &nbsp;<span>10%</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="extras_y-desc" scope="row">
                        Female
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div class="extras_result">
                            <p class="extras_p">
                               &nbsp;<span>30%</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="extras_y-desc" scope="row">
                        Unknown
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div class="extras_result">
                            <p class="extras_p">
                               &nbsp;<span>55%</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="extras_x-desc">

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
             </div>
         </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Why Did you put    jQuery(document).ready(function ($)  inside the function?(it's completely wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery(document).ready I don't think would trigger as this only works with full postbacks.

```
    var Manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    Manager.add_endRequest(function() {
        $(".extras_result").each(function () {
            // get the width of the bar from the span html
            var length = $(this).find("span").html();
            // Animate the width of the 'p' with a callback function
            $(this).find("p").animate({ 'width': length }, 2000, function () {
                // once the bar animation has finished, fade in the results
                $(this).find("span").fadeIn(300);
            });
        });
    });
```

this adds your same function to the end request event of the manager - you could filter it by the panel id I think (not sure how) or ideally on your button click add some sort of switch client side.

I haven't tested the above code but it SHOULD work.

Answer (score 0):

if you using this button for showing graph  only then you can restrict default behavior of btnPreviewGraph by using preventdefault() as follows

```
$("#btnPreviewGraph").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //your code continues
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the it under pageLoad() function if you are using updatepanel.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
   $(document).ready(function(){   

     $(".datePick").datepicker();  

     $(".collapsibleContainer").collapsiblePanel();  

   });         
}
```

it works fine for me. I am using the same.